# How to fix this e2e test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

Problem is that when you click on "Add Rule" button you get new "Search Term" and "Search textarea" fields. 
But protractor can't see them.

```
 it('On "Add new Audience Rule" page should have two rules and two 
    search Terms', () => {
    audiencePage.addRule.click().then(() => {
        expect(audiencePage.ORbutton.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        expect(audiencePage.searchTerms.count()).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

Error log:

```
1) Audience page: On "Add new Audience Rule" page should have two rules and two search Terms
  - Expected false to be true.
  - Expected 1 to equal 2.
```

Screenshot before and after clicked "Add Rule" btn: 
[image]

Comment: Can you initialise ORbutton and searchTerms in the test case rather than the page and check if it gets identified. For dynamic objects, you need to define objects again.

Comment: @Avinashs15 I am not sure that I follow you, how to initialise ORbutton and searchTerms in the test case?

Comment: var ORbutton =  element(by.xpath(''));
var searchTerms  = element(by.xpath(''));

In the test case rather than audiencePage

Comment: Ok tnx for reply, I will try.

Comment: You can try putting a 2s-5s sleep before expect methods to see if you have some timing issues. If that's the case, I suggest calling browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) and using explicit waits to validate if new fields are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work when you try it like this?

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    audiencePage.addRule.click();
});

it('On "Add new Audience Rule" page should have an OR button', () => {
    expect(audiencePage.ORbutton.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});

it('On "Add new Audience Rule" page should have two search Terms', () => {
    expect(audiencePage.searchTerms.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: Can it be a timing issue? You can test it by adding browser.sleep(5000) in the beforeAll method. If your test succeed after that, you need to build a wait for element to be visible.